# Nginx. 301 Moved Permanently при проксировании

Tags: nginx, proxypass

Конфиг nginx`a

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomainname.com;
    location /update_k3s_io {
        proxy_pass https://update.k3s.io/;
        proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        proxy_ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        proxy_ssl_verify_depth 2;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        #proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect ~^https://[^/]+(/.+)$ http://mydomainname.com/update_k3s_io$1;
    }

 }
```

При обращении постоянно получаю 301 Moved Permanently

```
[root@centos ~]# curl -v http://mydomainname.com/update_k3s_io/v1-release/channels
*   Trying 172.16.16.2...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to mydomainname.com (172.16.16.2) port 80 (#0)
> GET /update_k3s_io/v1-release/channels HTTP/1.1
> Host: mydomainname.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
>

< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.18.0
< Date: Sat, 05 Feb 2022 18:50:01 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< location: /v1-release/channels
< strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload
< CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
< Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=wKyi16WxuyuaHO08DrH7%2FzyNJopjnIXJKluUYVSKy61chEH8BHoMt%2BEWAPOE3Yo5mv%2Fi2n36vlpRyUjIq15OkzUWkbHPwlPf6tuAxqExdwuAhxdAyXisDk7XG6lWfZo%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
< NEL: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< CF-RAY: 6d8e527b2f863a5f-DME
<
* Connection #0 to host mydomainname.com left intact
```

URL вроде правильный получается, что может быть еще может ни так?

Comment: Как минимум надо в `location` дописать `/` в конце

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так должно работать:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomainname.com;
    location /update_k3s_io/ {
        proxy_pass https://update.k3s.io/;
        proxy_redirect / /update_k3s_io/;

        proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        proxy_ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        proxy_ssl_verify_depth 2;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    }
}
```

В вашем коде из-за отсутствия `/` в конце `location` при проксировании получается такой URL: `https://update.k3s.io//v1-release/channels` и сервер k3s пытается сказать вам, что ходить надо на нормальный URL без двойных слешей. Ну и `proxy_redirect` не работает потому что заголовок `Location` в ответе не содержит имени сервера.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало